# How to make a discord bot web dashboard?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, dashboard

Sometimes, discord bots have dashboards. These are panels on the web that let you control the settings of the bot and what not. So, I was wondering, what kind of tool would you use to create this? And, how would you connect it to the bot itself? I understand that it's not very realistic to expect somebody to tell me how to do this, step by step, so I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea of a dashboard is that it's mostly independent of the bot and communicating with it via a database and websockets. To find user data from the bot, use [oauth2](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) to make people be able to log in into your dashboard via their Discord account and then query your database, which has data from the bot. As a webframework, I reccomend Flask or Django.

This is not at all trivial.

Comment: could you give me a tutorial?
also, how do I access the database?

Comment: I am not able to find a Tutorial online for a web dashboard for a discord.py bot. Stackoverflow is for answering specifc questions and solving specific problems, not write 10 page tutorials. The best advice I can give is to look into web development and oauth2.